# how to validate radio button in multi step form

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

i have a multi step form of three steps and its working fine. Now , i want to add validations in it, especially for radio button. In first step, there is a radio button with eight options, and same in second step and in third field there are some input options.

here is my html:

```
<form id="msform" method="POST" action="abc.php">
    <!-- progressbar -->
    <ul id="progressbar">
        <li class="active"></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
    <!-- fieldsets -->
    <fieldset>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 my-2">
                <div class='btns'>
                    <label>
                        <input name="artist" type='radio'>
                        <span class='btn first'>Singers</span>
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-6 my-2">
                <div class='btns'>
                    <label>
                        <input name="artist" type='radio'>
                        <span class='btn'>Bands</span>
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-6 my-2">
                <div class='btns'>
                    <label>
                        <input name="artist" type='radio'>
                        <span class='btn'>Rappers</span>
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-6 my-2">
                <div class='btns'>
                    <label>
                        <input name="artist" type='radio'>
                        <span class='btn'>Djs</span>
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-6 my-2">
                <div class='btns'>
                    <label>
                        <input name="artist" type='radio'>
                        <span class='btn'>Comedians</span>
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-6 my-2">
                <div class='btns'>
                    <label>
                        <input name="artist" type='radio'>
                        <span class='btn'>Motivational Speakers</span>
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-6 my-2">
                <div class='btns'>
                    <label>
                        <input name="artist" type='radio'>
                        <span class='btn'>Dancers</span>
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-6 my-2">
                <div class='btns'>
                    <label>
                        <input name="artist" type='radio'>
                        <span class='btn'>Actors</span>
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="NEXT" />
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
        <h5 class="concierge-mobile desktop-view">Celeb Concierge</h5>
        <h2 class="artist-type">Type of Event</h2>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 my-2">
                <div class='btns'>
                    <label>
                        <input name="event" type='radio'>
                        <span class='btn first'>Wedding</span>
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-6 my-2">
                <div class='btns'>
                    <label>
                        <input name="event" type='radio'>
                        <span class='btn'>Private Party</span>
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-6 my-2">
                <div class='btns'>
                    <label>
                        <input name="event" type='radio'>
                        <span class='btn'>Brand Launch</span>
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-6 my-2">
                <div class='btns'>
                    <label>
                        <input name="event" type='radio'>
                        <span class='btn'>Corporate Get-Together</span>
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-6 my-2">
                <div class='btns'>
                    <label>
                        <input name="event" type='radio'>
                        <span class='btn'>Collegue Event</span>
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-6 my-2">
                <div class='btns'>
                    <label>
                        <input name="event" type='radio'>
                        <span class='btn'>Charity</span>
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-6 my-2">
                <div class='btns'>
                    <label>
                        <input name="event" type='radio'>
                        <span class='btn'>Photo/Video Shoot</span>
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-6 my-2">
                <div class='btns'>
                    <label>
                        <input name="event" type='radio'>
                        <span class='btn'>Concert</span>
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="BACK" />
        <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="NEXT" />
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
        <h5 class="concierge-mobile desktop-view">Celeb Concierge</h5>
        <h2 class="artist-type">Type of Event</h2>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 my-2">
                <h6 class="budget">Budget</h6>
                <div class="rangeslider">
                    <input class="min" name="range_1" type="range" min="1" max="100" value="10" />
                    <input class="max" name="range_1" type="range" min="1" max="100" value="90" />
                    <span class="range_min light left">10.000</span>
                    <span class="range_max light right">90.000</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 my-2">
                <input type="text" name="location" class="event-details" placeholder="Event Location" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 my-2">
                <input type="text" name="date" class="event-details" placeholder="Event Date" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 my-2">
                <input type="text" name="name" class="event-details" placeholder="Name" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 my-2">
                <input type="text" name="email" class="event-details" placeholder="Email Id" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 my-2">
                <input type="text" name="phone" class="event-details" placeholder="Phone Number" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="BACK" />
        <button class="book-button" type="submit">SUBMIT</button>
    </fieldset>

</form>
```

here is my script:

```
//jQuery time
var current_fs, next_fs, previous_fs; //fieldsets
var left, opacity, scale; //fieldset properties which we will animate
var animating; //flag to prevent quick multi-click glitches

$(".next").click(function(){
  if(animating) return false;
  animating = true;

  current_fs = $(this).parent();
  next_fs = $(this).parent().next();

  //activate next step on progressbar using the index of next_fs
  $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(next_fs)).addClass("active");

  //show the next fieldset
  next_fs.show(); 
  //hide the current fieldset with style
  current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
    step: function(now, mx) {
      //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
      //1. scale current_fs down to 80%
      scale = 1 - (1 - now) * 0.2;
      //2. bring next_fs from the right(50%)
      left = (now * 50)+"%";
      //3. increase opacity of next_fs to 1 as it moves in
      opacity = 1 - now;
      current_fs.css({
        'transform': 'scale('+scale+')',
        'position': 'absolute'
      });
      next_fs.css({'left': left, 'opacity': opacity});
    }, 
    duration: 800, 
    complete: function(){
      current_fs.hide();
      animating = false;
    }, 
    //this comes from the custom easing plugin
    easing: 'easeInOutBack'
  });
});

$(".previous").click(function(){
  if(animating) return false;
  animating = true;

  current_fs = $(this).parent();
  previous_fs = $(this).parent().prev();

  //de-activate current step on progressbar
  $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(current_fs)).removeClass("active");

  //show the previous fieldset
  previous_fs.show(); 
  //hide the current fieldset with style
  current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
    step: function(now, mx) {
      //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
      //1. scale previous_fs from 80% to 100%
      scale = 0.8 + (1 - now) * 0.2;
      //2. take current_fs to the right(50%) - from 0%
      left = ((1-now) * 50)+"%";
      //3. increase opacity of previous_fs to 1 as it moves in
      opacity = 1 - now;
      current_fs.css({'left': left});
      previous_fs.css({'transform': 'scale('+scale+')', 'opacity': opacity});
    }, 
    duration: 800, 
    complete: function(){
      current_fs.hide();
      animating = false;
    }, 
    //this comes from the custom easing plugin
    easing: 'easeInOutBack'
  });
});

$(".submit").click(function(){
  return false;
})
```

please help me out, thanks in advance

Comment: And now you want us to do the programming of that functionality for you? Please specify cleary what part of the code you're having a problem with.

Comment: Please go read [ask]. You are supposed to ask an actual specific question here - dropping a bunch of code and using “how to” in the question title isn’t really that. So please properly explain what exactly you are having a problem with here.

Comment: where is your default selected radio button?